# Duplicate "replace" method in a single class

Tags: java, methods, documentfilter

I have found myself with an obstacle. I am developing a calculator project I have, and one of the objects in it is the JFormattedTextField, but I think we can call it just "text field". In the mentioned object, I wanted to allow only digits to be typed in it, as well as having a limit on the numbers that could be typed.

So I created the CalculatorsFilter class, and inside it, the code that would run the two objectives I wanted, so we can separate the class as, the digit filter:

```
public class CalculatorsFilter extends DocumentFilter {
        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, 
                AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            super.insertString(fb, offset, revise(text), attr);
        }

        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
                            AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, revise(text), attrs);
        }

        private String revise(String text) {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text);
            int index = 0;
            while (index < builder.length()) {

                if (accept(builder.charAt(index))) {
                    index++;

                } else {

                    builder.deleteCharAt(index);

                }
            }

            return builder.toString();
        }

        public boolean accept(final char c) {
            return Character.isDigit(c) || c == '.' || c == '-' || c == '+';
        }
```

And the second part, which is the limit "creator":

```
 private final int numlimit;

        public CalculatorsFilter(int limit) {
                 if (limit <= 0) {
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number limit can not be <= 0");
                 }
                 this.numlimit = limit;
        }

             public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                 final int currentLength = fb.getDocument().getLength();
                 final int overLimit = (currentLength + text.length()) - numlimit - length;
                 if (overLimit > 0) {
                     text = text.substring(0, text.length() - overLimit);
                 }
                 if (text.length() > 0) {
                     super.replace(fb, offset, currentLength, text, attrs); 
                 }
        }
}
```

As you probably have noticed, the problem here is that I have the same methods inside the same class, the method replace(). And of course, it gives an error message, as I actually expected. However, if I try to rename one of them, let's say, to "replace1", the renamed method will not work anymore, even if the error message went away.
Another solution I have tried, is what seemed to be the simplest, just creating another class for each of these filters I wanted. However again, the obstacle is that I cannot use...

```
//intField is the JFormattedTextField.
intField.setDocumentFilter();
```

two times on my Main class, which means I can't use one class to each filter. Have I done something wrong while trying to fix, or is there a way to solve the duplicate method error without compromising one of them?

Comment: Rename your "second" `replace` method (and make it `private` as well; not strictly necessary, but good design), then **call** the renamed method from the "real" `replace`.

Comment: Um... How do I call it?... I am kind of new to programming, I know what "Calling a method" means, but I don't know how.

Comment: You'd pass It all of `replace`'s arguments, in the same order, just like you're doing with `super.replace` now.

Comment: When I do it the program says the variables cannot be resolved. I tried calling using ```this.replace1(//variables here)``` inside of the "real" replace, and no success... But I may put a bit more brain in it, thank you for being the only one answering :)